# How I can get custom field's current value?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have "Color Filters for WooCommerce" plugin and "color" taxonomy.

Each taxonomy have one custom field - color picker.

I want to display on archive page current color picker value of each product's.

I can call

```
get_option( 'nm_taxonomy_colors' );
```

And I'll get all values from this field, but I need only current.

This plugin have [doc](https://www.elementous.com/documentation/color-filters-for-woocommerce/modifications-and-development/), but I don't know how I can use this filters

```
elm_cf_get_terms_args
elm_cf_color_style_attribute
```